# Raspberry Pi4 not booting with Ubuntu MATE 20.04

Tags: mate, sd-card

I am running a Pi400 4GB. I've got the device connected to a monitor. I previously tried ubuntu20.04 and this loaded okay.

When trying Ubuntu MATE 20.04 64bit the Pi very quickly turns off. I've turned the Pi on without the SD card in and the general Pi screen loads stating the SD card isn't inserted. Once I insert the page turns to a colour wheel style page before going blank and the green light on the Pi400 disappears.

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Ubuntu MATE version: https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/arm64/focal/

Pi 400 version: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/raspberry-pi/2048262

(I've read similar questions regarding HDMI display but this doesn't seem to be the issue as the Pi itself turns off.)

Comment: This has happened to my a couple of times, and it was caused by a power supply that wasn't powerful enough. Could that be the case here?

Comment: @Jos I don't think so! I've tried a range of power supplies which power my phone quite happily. If anything they may be on the higher end of that's acceptable.

Comment: Most phones need a lot *less* than the Pi: https://support.thepihut.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015199058-How-do-I-power-a-Raspberry-Pi-400-

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to check power supply voltage if you are not using official power supply by Raspberry Pi foundation and if you aren't experiencing the same issue with other operating systems like Raspberry Pi OS then format your SD card flash Ubuntu Mate properly. Using Raspberry Pi imager is one of the easiest ways. I hope that solves your issue. : )

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu Server 20.04 using Raspberry Pi Imager first.
Then, use https://github.com/wimpysworld/desktopify to get yourself a Mate 20.04.
It works for me.